# Is there anyway to control the TTL when using Golang http.server?

Tags: go, http, ttl

This is might seem a bit strange but I want to be able to control the TTL of HTTP responses from a golang http.Server. It is okay if the entire server has a global control, I don't need to control it per response. I do that net.Conn has a method called `SetHopLimit` to control TTL but I cannot figure out anyway to access that from inside a server handler.

Comment: The server can have global control via the `Listener`: https://pkg.go.dev/net#ListenConfig

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your use case? I'm curious in which case you would like to set the ttl for the Response.

Comment: Could you specify what exactly you mean with TTL? Time to response?

Comment: IP TTLs are set per-packet, not per session, which is why there's not a convenient binding for that in `http.Server`. If you need that low-level of customization, you'll need to implement your own `net.Listener`, which takes care of its own `net.Conn`, which takes care of... and so on. Start by reading what the stdlib is doing under the covers.

Comment: Honestly, it'd be easier and more efficient to write an eBPF program that does this for all network connections. Here's a good article on _accessing_ those values. Mutating is an exercise left up to you: https://blog.cloudflare.com/epbf_sockets_hop_distance

Comment: The TTL of the response packages... I would throw in "separation of concerns" here.  Side note: what about `((f|s)?cgi])? sockets` you might want to use later? Sounds like a XY problem. What do you want to achieve with controlling the TTL? @coxley Oh, nice catch, I did not get that.